# React navigation header right button

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I want add button in react-native header , the button is to mas and unmask password in the page, the problem on click when i change the state to change secureTextEntry value, the icon wont change will keep as the initial value;
the function is working fine but the icon cant change

```
this.state.secureTextEntry ? "eye" : "eye-slash"
```

this is the main code

```
 class ChangePasswordScreen extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.state = {
         newPassword: null,
         currentPassword: null,
         confirmPassword: null,
         errors: [],
         secureTextEntry: true

     };

     this.maskPassword = this.maskPassword.bind(this)
 }
 componentDidMount() {
     this.props.navigation.setParams({
         headerRight: ( < TouchableOpacity onPress = {
                 () => {
                     this.maskPassword();
                 }
             } > < Icon style = {
                 styles.eyeIcon
             }
             name = {
                 this.state.secureTextEntry ? "eye" : "eye-slash"
             }
             size = {
                 20
             }
             color = {
                 Colors.WHITE
             }
             /></TouchableOpacity > )
     })
 }
 static navigationOptions = ({
     navigation
 }) => {
     return {
         // headerTitle: <LogoTitle />,
         headerRight: navigation.state.params && navigation.state.params.headerRight,
     };
 };
 maskPassword = () => {
     this.setState({
         secureTextEntry: !this.state.secureTextEntry
     })

 }
```

}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is **this.setState** will not re-render header component . if you want to change header right then you have to call **setParams** again

Try this code in **componentDidMount**

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.navigation.setParams({
      headerRight: this.setHeaderRight(this.state.secureTextEntry)
    });
  }
```

**Set function for header right**

```
setHeaderRight = state => {
    //console.log("setHeaderRight", this.state.secureTextEntry);
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => {
          this.maskPassword();
        }}
      >
        <Icon
          style={styles.eyeIcon}
          name={state ? "eye" : "eye-slash"}
          size={20}
          color={Colors.WHITE}
        />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  };
```

**Set header right again when state set**

```
maskPassword = () => {
    this.setState({
      secureTextEntry: !this.state.secureTextEntry
    });
    this.props.navigation.setParams({
      headerRight: this.setHeaderRight(!this.state.secureTextEntry)
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 16):

Kinda late, might help someone nevertheless.

If you wish to add a button to the header of a screen, from the screen itself, not the App.js file and you are using a functional component, it goes like this:

```
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native'

export function Component() {
  const nav = useNavigation();
  useEffect(() => {
    nav.setOptions({
      headerRight: () => <Button />,
    });
  }, []);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are setting a Component as a navigation param on Component mount and passing in a state value at the time the Component mounted.

This param never gets changed or updated again so the navigation header never gets re rendered.

A better way would be to pass the value of state directly as a navigation param and use that in the component that is used directly in the navigationOptions