# navigation.navigate on a button in headerRight of the Stack Navigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Firstly, I have the same issue as [Button linking in headerRight](https://forums.expo.io/t/button-linking-to-a-screen-in-headerright-tab/33599). But their solution was simply using `functional` over `component`. I cannot simply switch to `functional` code as I need to use `componentDidMount`, so I really need solution for a `component` based `headerRight` navigation usage.

Stack

```
  function MyStack() {
    return (
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Root"
          component={BottomTabs}
          options={{
            headerRight: ({ navigation }) => (
              <View>
                <Button
                  onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Profile')}
                </Button>
              </View>
            ),
          }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    );
  }
```

BottomTabs

```
const BottomTabs = createBottomTabNavigator();
function MyTabs() {
  return (
    <BottomTabs.Navigator
    ...
```

This will bring an error that navigation is not available there. Okay that's right, as you cannot use navigation directly in the definition of the Stack Navigator.

Even using:

```
headerRight: () => {
   return <ProfileButtonScreen/>
},
```

did not help as on that component I still not have the navigation available.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49593002/custom-function-in-headerright-of-stacknavigator-in-react-native) is too less info but is already going in the right direction. And finally [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61461356/1077633) gave me the idea about misusing the BottomTabs for the defining of the headerRight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Stack**

```
  function MyStack() {
    return (
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Root"
          component={BottomTabs}
        />
        <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    );
  }
```

**BottomTabs**

```
const BottomTabs = createBottomTabNavigator();
function MyTabs({ navigation, route }) {
  navigation.setOptions({
    headerRight: () => (
      <View>
        <Button
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Profile')}
          title="To Profile"
        >
        </Button>
      </View>
    ),
  });

  return (
    <BottomTabs.Navigator
    ...
```

This will now let you have a **clickable button** on **stack navigation header**.

[image: clickable button on stack navigation header]